# Bus Error (after updating my macbook pro to sonoma 14.0)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, bus-error

I recently updated my macbook to Sonoma 14.0 and am unable to run this program for a BST. It used to run just fine before I updated my laptop and now I'm getting a bus error. I'm fairly new at coding and don't know what to do to fix this. I would appreciate some help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

template<typename Char> class BST {
public:  
    struct Node {
        Char data; 
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };
    Node* rootNode;

    BST() {
        rootNode->data = '\0';
        rootNode->left = nullptr;
        rootNode->right = nullptr;
    }

    Node* createNode(char ch) {
        Node* nn = new Node;
        nn->data = ch;
        nn->left = nullptr;
        nn->right = nullptr;
        return nn;
    }

    void insert(char myChar) {
        insertHelper(rootNode, myChar);
    }

    void inOrderTraversal() {
        inOrderTraversalHelper(rootNode);
    }

    void preOrderTraversal() {
        preOrderTraversalHelper(rootNode);
    }

    void postOrderTraversal() {
        postOrderTraversalHelper(rootNode);
    }    

private:
    char insertHelper(Node* &root, char ch) {
        if (root->data == '\0') {
            root->data = ch;
        } else if ( ch < root->data) {
            if (root -> left == nullptr) {
                root -> left = createNode(ch);
            } else {
                insertHelper(root->left, ch);
            } 
        } else {
            if ( ch > root->data) {
                if (root -> right == nullptr) {
                root -> right = createNode(ch);
            } else {
                insertHelper(root->right, ch);
            }
            }
        } return ch;
    }

    void inOrderTraversalHelper(Node* node) {
        if (node != nullptr) {
            inOrderTraversalHelper(node->left); 
            cout << node->data << " ";           
            inOrderTraversalHelper(node->right); 
        }
    }

    void preOrderTraversalHelper(Node* node) {
        if (node != nullptr) {
            cout << node->data << " ";           
            preOrderTraversalHelper(node->left);  
            preOrderTraversalHelper(node->right); 
        }
    }

    void postOrderTraversalHelper(Node* node) {
        if (node != nullptr) {
            postOrderTraversalHelper(node->left); 
            postOrderTraversalHelper(node->right);
            cout << node->data << " ";          
        }
    }
};

int main () {
    BST<char> cisp_bst; 
    cisp_bst.insert('k');
    cisp_bst.insert('e');
    cisp_bst.insert('v');
    cisp_bst.insert('b');
    cisp_bst.insert('g');
    cisp_bst.insert('p');
    cisp_bst.insert('y');

    cout << "\n" << "In order traversal: ";
    cisp_bst.inOrderTraversal();
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Post-order traversal: ";
    cisp_bst.postOrderTraversal();
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Pre-order traversal: ";
    cisp_bst.preOrderTraversal();
    cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
};
```

It ran just fine before but now it gives me a bus error. The debugger says it crashes in the first line of the constructor. (assigning data to '\0')

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. `In constructor BST<Char>::BST(), warning: '*this.BST<char>::rootNode' is used uninitialized, at rootNode->data = '\0';`

Comment: You are using `rootNode` in BST's constructor w/o initializing it. Looks like `createNode` should initialize it

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/995714)

Answer (score 1):

I try to debug with `lldb` on my macbook(also Sonoma 14.0), and get the error message:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100002bbc)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100002dfc a.out`BST<char>::BST(this=0x000000016fdfefc0) at test.cpp:15:20
   12     Node *rootNode;
   13  
   14     BST() {
-> 15       rootNode->data = '\0';
   16       rootNode->left = nullptr;
   17       rootNode->right = nullptr;
   18     }
Target 1: (a.out) stopped.
```

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that your program is trying to access memory that it doesn't have permission to access. And for your code, it happens in the constructor of your `BST` class.

So the solution is:

1. Change your `BST()` from

```cpp
BST() {
    rootNode->data = '\0';
    rootNode->left = nullptr;
    rootNode->right = nullptr;
}
```

To:

```cpp
BST() {
    rootNode = nullptr;
}
```

2. And change the first `if-statement` of the `insertHelper()` from:

```cpp
if (root->data == '\0') {
    root->data = ch;
}
```

To:

```cpp
if (root == nullptr) {
   root = createNode(ch);
}
```

This method works on my macbook, and I got this result:

```
In order traversal: b e g k p v y 

Post-order traversal: b g e p y v k 

Pre-order traversal: k e b g v p y
```

Hope this also works for you.